# I don't want to auto reflect chart with $watch in angulars js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, linechart

Right now I am implementing line chart in angular js. And I have written one directive for this, So it is working fine, But when I am putted $watch in this directive then every time chart will updating continuously. I want to use $watch for some dynamic change after loaded the page.

```
angular.module('app.abc').directive('linechart', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template:'',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.$watch(function(){
                var lineOptions = {                   
               scaleShowGridLines : true,            
               scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",               
               scaleGridLineWidth : 1,              
              bezierCurve : true,                   
            };    
            var lineData = { labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
                datasets: [                   
                    {
                        label: "My Second dataset",
                        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                    }
                ]
            };              

            var ctx = element[0].getContext("2d");
            var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineData, lineOptions); 
            })           
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
 <canvas style="display: block;"  linechart height="120" ></canvas>
```

Line chart reflecting updates is contiguously. But I don't want to reflection continuously. I have tried to put my ctx object outside of $watch, but chart is not showing anything. Actually I am new in angular js and also new in directives. Please give me idea how handle this directive with $watch. I have seen one demo(based on javascript) example https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/mJRrKw

Comment: When using `$watch [$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);]`; the `watchExp` The expression being watched, it is evaluated at every digest cycle. `listener`: A callback, fired when the watch is first set, and then each time that during the digest cycle that a change for `watchExp‘s` value is detected. The initial call on setup is meant to store an initial value for the expression.

Comment: @sumit .thanks for the comment.could you provide some code related to my code.because I am new in angular.